# Selenium Webdriver: how to drag element to another iframe?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium chrome webdriver with java, I need help dragging an element out of an iframe and onto another element in a different iframe. Has anyone done this before and if so could you post an example for me?

Here is what I've tried so far, also I have tried many other solutions:

```
            WebElement Atom = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Circle']"));
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            driver.switchTo().frame("treeNavigation");
            WebElement Event = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Line']"));

         // Create Actions object passing in a WebDriver object
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

            // Chain some calls together and call build
            Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(Atom)
              .moveToElement(Event)
              .release(Event)
              .build();

            // Perform the actions
            dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: can we see some code?  preferably of the HTML in question of the iframes, and the java code you've tried so far

Comment: I added some code I have tried.

Comment: do you have a public url with the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done that yet, but I would like to try the following;
move to the source iframe, get the element, clickAndHold, build, perform. Then switch to default content, then switch to target iframe, moveToElement, release, build, perform.
Any sample test page would help. Thanks.